# out of line sql index creation issue Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

Can someone explain me what wrong with the syntax. I want to add constraints primary key and unique but also want to use the same index (composite index).

```
create table val (
val1 number, val2 number,
constraint val_pk primary key(val1) using index(create index val_index on val(val1,val2)),
constraint val_unique unique (val2) using index val_index);
```

its giving me an error

```
create table val (
val1 number, val2 number,
constraint val_pk primary key(val1) using index(create index val_index on val(val1,val2)),
constraint val_unique unique (val2) using index val_index)
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-14196: Specified index cannot be used to enforce the constraint.
14196. 00000 -  "Specified index cannot be used to enforce the constraint."
*Cause:    The index specified to enforce the constraint is unsuitable
           for the purpose.
*Action:   Specify a suitable index or allow one to be built automatically.
```

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Why would an index on `val1, val2` be suitable to enforce a unique constraint on `val2`?  Could you define `val_index` in the opposite order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enforce primary key or unique constraints, Oracle uses an index.

By default, if a suitable index doesn't already exist, Oracle will automatically create a unique index with the same columns and in the same order as the constraint definition.

However, Oracle is also capable of using non-unique indexes, and the columns don't need to be identical to the ones in the constraint.

However, for an index to be usable, the ***leading*** columns of the index need to include ***all*** the columns defined in the constraint.

So in your case, if you have an index defined as:

```
create index val_index on val(val1,val2)
```

... it can be used to enforce the primary key on `val1`, because `val1` is the ***leading*** column in the index.

But it cannot be used to enforce the unique constraint on `val2`, because `val2` is the 2nd column in the index.

On the other hand, it you defined a unique constraint on `(val1, val2)` or `(val2, val1)`, both of those combinations can use the index successfully, because they are both covered by the ***leading*** columns of the index (the 1st and 2nd columns of the index). Of course, having both constraints is redundant, so it doesn't make sense to do that.

In your case, having what are essentially 2 different unique constraints on 2 different columns will require at least 2 indexes. You will not be able to enforce both constraints with a single index.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite clear.  A unique condition on `val2` cannot be enforced by a compound index on `(val1, val2)`.

Why do you feel the need to specify indexes anyway?  Why not just use:

```
contraint unq_table_val2 unique(val2)
```